# Dash() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_pages' running on WSGI

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a dash application built on several pages from an example from the documentation - https://dash.plotly.com/urls and it works locally, but for some reason on the host - python.everywhere it does not work., when I start, I encounter the error Dash() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_pages' And before I added a few pages, everything worked fine. Tell me what I'm doing wrong and what could be the reason.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0DkG.png)

## App.py

thi is just code from example i only added server = app.server

```py
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
import dash

app = Dash(__name__, use_pages=True)
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1('Multi-page app with Dash Pages'),

    html.Div(
        [
            html.Div(
                dcc.Link(
                    f"{page['name']} - {page['path']}", href=page["relative_path"]
                )
            )
            for page in dash.page_registry.values()
        ]
    ),

    dash.page_container
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

## WSGI

```
import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = '/home/Andreson/mysite'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px
from dash_bootstrap_templates import load_figure_template
from app import app
application = app.server
```

I tried to run the application without use_pages=True - everything worked, I tried to use a Dash (**name**, server = server, use_pages=True) and of course I searched the entire Internet in search of an answer. But since there is no answer, I think this is some little thing that people dont ask  about, so I apologize in advance for a possibly stupid question.

Comment: I still don't know what the problem is, so I went the other way and just rewrote the application. Here is the example how can you create a multipage app another way based on switching layout on mayn page and, yes,this realisation works perfectly for my app:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/creating-a-multi-page-dash-application-ab38b4b91bf5

Note: all callbacks should be in app.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when trying to host a dashboard on pythonanywhere but I managed to solve it. While you already found a solution, I'm going to post my findings here for future reference.

I think the reason why the error happened is because the default version of Flask used by pythonanywhere contained an older version of dash. Luckily, pythonanywhere allows you to create your own virtual environment on which to install packages. This turned out to be the solution because after creating my own virtual environment and installing the necessary packages the dash app ran as expected.

Comment: Yep, you're right, I set up a virtual environment and everything work now.